# Datatables plugin

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've looked on the website but I can not find out how to put the sInfo into the table footer for the datatables plugin for jQuery. I've looked into their documentation but just am not seeing anything. Any ideas?

Edit Post:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#usersPageList').dataTable( {
    "sDom": 'rt<"pagination"p>',
    "iDisplayLength": 1,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
} );

var info = $('.dataTables_info')
var clone = info.clone();
info.hide();
$('tfoot').append(clone);  

});
```

Edit Post 2:

[Pastebin Code](http://pastebin.com/2j9NyLPu)

Comment: Aware me on 'sinfo,' as I may be able to help.

Comment: The main part I'm looking for is the Showing x rows of x total or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you need to play a little with the [sDom](http://www.datatables.net/usage/options) option. Taken from the documentation:

```
This initialisation variable allows you to specify exactly where in the DOM you want DataTables to inject the various controls it adds to the page (for example you might want the pagination controls at the top of the table). DIV elements (with or without a custom class) can also be added to aid styling. The follow syntax is used:
The following options are allowed:

'l' - Length changing
'f' - Filtering input
't' - The table!
'i' - Information
'p' - Pagination
'r' - pRocessing
The following constants are allowed:
'H' - jQueryUI theme "header" classes ('fg-toolbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-tl ui-corner-tr ui-helper-clearfix')
'F' - jQueryUI theme "footer" classes ('fg-toolbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-bl ui-corner-br ui-helper-clearfix')
The following syntax is expected:
'<' and '>' - div elements
'<"class" and '>' - div with a class
'<"#id" and '>' - div with an ID
Examples:
'<"wrapper"flipt>', '<lf<t>ip>'
```

so for example if you do (i suppose you are using jquery UI <"H"lfr>t<"F"ip> you have the length changing, the filter and the "processing..." (if you have ajax enabled) in the header, the you have the table, then you have info and pagination in the footer. If you want you can use the letters more than one time so you can put the info twice or thrice if you want.

EDIT - in your comment you say you want to add the  tfoot of your table. In that case you could just add it manually:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#usersPageList').dataTable( {
    "sDom": 'rti<"pagination"p>',//add i here this is the number of records
    "iDisplayLength": 1,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
} );

var info = $('.dataTables_info')
$('tfoot').append(info);  

});
```

Comment: But I'm talking about the table footer and not sure how that would be like.

Comment: I updated my post above to show you the jquery code I have which does not sole the current problem.

Comment: That is because you are not displaying table info: i edit my answer

Comment: However one last thing it does NOT update with the Showing so many records on each page.

Comment: Post also the HTML, i can try to look for a solution

Comment: I wanted to thank you for looking into this for me but I have included a link to my full code Nicola.

Comment: I edited my answer not to use clone: in this way the values update correctly

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the [`bInfo` option](http://datatables.net/usage/features)?

> Enable or disable the table
>   information display. This shows
>   information about the data that is
>   currently visible on the page,
>   including information about filtered
>   data if that action is being
>   performed.

Comment: I'm sorry I thought I saw it as sInfo. But how do I display it in teh table footer not the page footer

Comment: @Jeff: It looks like that information is displayed beneath the table, but not actually in the `tfoot` element. Is that where you want it?

Comment: I'd like to have it nicely displayed nicely in the tfoot if at all possible.

Comment: I just saw where I saw the sInfo though. It was here. http://datatables.net/usage/i18n

Comment: Do you know how this is accomplished?

Comment: @Jeff: You could manually move that html into the `tfoot` after the table is rendered. Why is it so important that it's in the table footer?

Comment: Its not that important however its just something I would prefer to have happen.